# creating a command based logger program

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, logging, indexoutofboundsexception

i'm currently trying to make a java program which creates and writes a log file.

it has 2 classes (one for request, one for worker code). one class has a textfield and allows you to enter a command. command should be like 'log start' or 'log stop'.

so request class sends the command as a string, worker class gets the command, parses it and executes instructions (start logging, stop logging.

my problem is: application doesn't stop logging when user enters a 'stop' command. well, it doesn't stop after 3 log entries (that's the problem. i want to stop it any time user enters the command) you will understand the problem better when you take a look at the code.

i know i'm making a very basic mistake here but somehow currently can't figure it out and want your opinion on this problem. (i showed the problematic are in the code) Thank you.

error:

```
Exception in thread "stoplogging" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Response$ClientProcess$1StopperThread.run(Response.java:109)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Request class:

```
public class Request extends JFrame {
private JTextArea consoleArea = new JTextArea();
private JTextField cmd_prompt = new JTextField();
private JLabel cmd_label = new JLabel("Enter command: ");

// ********IP PORT TEXTFIELDS & CONNECT BUTTON*******  !!!!

private DataOutputStream output; 
private DataInputStream input;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Request();
}

Socket socket = null;
String command;
public Request (){
    JPanel requestPanel = new JPanel();
    requestPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setTitle("Project_3002_CLIENT");
    requestPanel.add(cmd_label, BorderLayout.WEST);
    requestPanel.add(cmd_prompt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(requestPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    add(new JScrollPane(consoleArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Font font = new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 15);
    cmd_prompt.setFont(font);
    cmd_prompt.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    cmd_prompt.addActionListener(new TextFieldListener());
    setSize(600, 270);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    consoleArea.setFont(font);
    setVisible(true);

    String ip = "127.0.0.1"; // THIS WILL BE CHANGED (make custom) --extra jframe
    int port = 4588; // THIS WILL BE CHANGED (make custom) -- extra jframe
    try {
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        //IO connection stuff
        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        consoleArea.append("Connection refused. Please check if the server is running.\n");
    }

}

class SenderThirty implements Runnable{

    Thread send30secs;
    public SenderThirty(){
    }

    public SenderThirty(String send30s){
        send30secs = new Thread(this, send30s);
        send30secs.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            output.writeUTF(command);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private class TextFieldListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            command = cmd_prompt.getText();

            if (command.contains("start") == true){

                Thread sendstart = new Thread(new SenderThirty(), "send");
                sendstart.start();
                //continue
            }

            else if (command.contains("stop") == true){
                Thread sendstop = new Thread(new SenderThirty(), "send");
                sendstop.start();
                //continue
            }

            else {consoleArea.append("\nInvalid command\n");}


        } catch (Exception e1) {
            consoleArea.append("\nERR!\n");
        }
    }
}}
```

Worker class:

```
public class Response {
String path = "";

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Response();
}

ServerSocket resp_sock;
public Response() throws InterruptedException {

    int port = 4588;
    try {
        resp_sock = new ServerSocket(port);

        int clientNo = 1;

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = resp_sock.accept();


            // client's IP address
            InetAddress client_addr = socket.getInetAddress();

            ClientProcess task = new ClientProcess(socket);
            new Thread(task).start();

            clientNo++;
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }

}

class ClientProcess implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket; 

    public ClientProcess(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            final DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());//from client
            //DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());//to client

            while(true){
                String prompt = input.readUTF();
                String command[] = prompt.split(" ");
                final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog"); 
                FileHandler fh;             
                fh = new FileHandler("C:\\..path..\\logfile.log");  
                logger.addHandler(fh);                      
                SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
                fh.setFormatter(formatter);




                class StopperThread implements Runnable{
                    public StopperThread(){
                    }           
                    @Override
                    public void run() { 
                        try { ////////////////////////////////////////***PROBLEM IS IN THIS TRY BLOCK***
                            String next_prompt;
                            next_prompt = input.readUTF();
                            String nextCommand[] = next_prompt.split(" ");

                            if(nextCommand[1].equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
                                logger.info("STOPPED   " + new Date() + "  \n");
                                System.exit(0);}

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }}






                if(command[1].equalsIgnoreCase("start")){
                    try {

                        while(true){
                            logger.info("RUNNING   " + new Date() + "  \n");
                            Thread.sleep(5000);

                            Thread stoplogging = new Thread(new StopperThread(), "stoplogging");
                            stoplogging.start();

                        }

                    } catch (SecurityException e) {  
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }  
                }


                if(command[1].equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
                    logger.info("STOPPED   " + new Date() + "  \n");  
                }


            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(nextCommand[1].equals...)` is most likely the culprit.

It will throw a NPE if there is no space (" ") in the string you split, in which case nextCommand's length will be 1, not 2.

You should check the length beforehand. Note: same potential error with `command[1]`.

Comment: thanks i will fix that. but my main problem is still occurring when the request has 2 items [log, stop]  first item is trivial here. what i need is, stopping the logging process wherever the stop request comes in. it can stop logging after 1 or 2 log entries (it logs every 5 seconds) but after 3 entries, if i try to stop, nothing happens and if i sen command several times rapidly, i get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. do you have any opinion with that?

Comment: @AdamCosgrove There are several potential problems, one being that you share data across threads without proper synchronization. So it is very possible that one thread makes a change and that the other threads don't see it. I suggest you try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the behaviour and post a new question.